# If the current of the branches in a parallel circuit always add up to the same total, why isn't this true in this example?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, batteries

Here is a picture:

[image: Circuit Diagram]

I did some math and got this table:

[image: Table of Calculations]

Why doesn't the current add up to the total, since it's supposed to in a parallel circuit? I used Ohm's law to calculate everything. My suspicion is that Ohm's law doesn't apply for the total column, and I should add up the currents in the other columns instead. Would this be the correct approach?

Comment: -1 Why do you think the equivalent resistance is $13000~ \Omega$? Apparently you haven't done any research about combining resistances or you would have realized your mistake.

Comment: @BillN I have done research, I just never thought to ask that question. I'm completely new to this subject, have seen one slideshow from school that told me that was how you added resistances and never thought to question it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Resistors in parallel don't add like $R_{tot}=R_1+R_2+R_3$, they add like $\frac{1}{R_{tot}}= \frac{1}{R_1} + \frac{1}{R_2}+\frac{1}{R_3}$.

Comment: Thanks! What about resistors in series? Do they add differently?

Comment: @BrianZhang, do the heights of several people standing next to each other "add up" differently than the heights of people standing on each others' shoulders?

Comment: @BrianZhang Resistors in series add like $R_{tot} = R_1+ R_2 + R_3+ \ldots$.  See e.g. [this tutorial](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/resistor/res_5.html) for more.

Comment: @J.Murray Awesome source! Thanks a ton.